# How to add a JS package to a Flutter Web project, so that it is accessible from my own JS scripts?

Tags: javascript, flutter

I think the title is a bit confusing, so I'll try to elaborate.

I have a Flutter Web app in which I use some JS code, specifically the ethers package (but the package itself is not important). The way I currently use it is:

- Add js package as dependency:

```yaml
dependencies:
  js: ^0.6.7
```

- Add this script tag to index.html:

```html
<script
  src="https://cdn.ethers.io/lib/ethers-5.7.2.umd.min.js"
  type="application/javascript"
></script>
```

- Create bindings between Dart and JS, for example:

```dart
@JS('ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider')
class _JsonRpcProvider {
  external _JsonRpcProvider([String? rpcUrl]);
  external dynamic getBlockNumber();
}

class JsonRpcProvider {
  late final _JsonRpcProvider _provider;

  JsonRpcProvider([String? rpcUrl]) {
    _provider = _JsonRpcProvider(rpcUrl);
  }

  Future<int> getBlockNumber() =>
      promiseToFuture<int>(_provider.getBlockNumber());
}
```

So from Flutter I can just call `var provider = JsonRpcProvider(url)` and it is basically translated to JS as `new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(url)`.

This is probably the most optimal way to use JS from Flutter. But now I want to test another package and it would take too damn long to create all necessary bindings, especially as I'm unsure whether I would end up using it or not.

So what I actually want is, instead of this proper way to call JS code, to use a "dirty" way. Specifically, instead of calling the package's functions from Dart directly I want to write my own JS script, which would import and use the package, and then just call the script from Flutter.

Using the example from above I imagine it to look smth like this (pseudocode):

```js
// myscript.js

import { ethers } from "https://cdn.ethers.io/lib/ethers-5.7.2.umd.min.js"

createProvider(url) {
    // save it to window so that can use it from other functions later
    window.myProvider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(url);
}

// call createProvider from Flutter
```

This doesn't work. The error says that there is no ethers defined.

Unfortunately, I know very little about JS. I don't know how to property import and use stuff, and there's so much information about modules and imports and requires and whatever, I don't understand it and, frankly, since this is just to play around with a package, I don't particularly want to learn it, since I don't work with JS that much.

Can you advise on how to properly add a JS package to a Flutter Web project, so that it is accessible from my own JS scripts? If it's possible to add a package in a way that would make it accessible from both JS and Flutter, that would be very cool.